# Mozilla and IE modifies how my drop down list look, but chrome doesn't

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I view my drop down list in chrome it looks perfect, but when I view it in mozilla or IE it adds a drop down arrow which i don't want. I have tried

```
-moz-appearance:none;
```

and

```
 opacity:0;
```

Which none of them solved my problem correctly. How do I get ride of that drop down arrow?

Here is one of my drop down lists:

```
<asp:DropDownList id="DropDownList3" 
        runat="server" 
        AutoPostBack="True" 
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
        DataTextField="Plant" 
        DataValueField="Plant" 
            Width="156px" 

        Font-Bold="true" 
            Font-Size="x-Large" 
           style="margin-left: 250px; margin-top:-44.5px;
                  margin-bottom:-20px; 
                  background-color: #FFFFFF; box-shadow:none;
                  outline-color: #FFFFFF; 
                  border: none; 
                  text-align: right;" 
                 Enabled="False">
                </asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: Can you post the code of your your dropdown?

Comment: Styling select lists for cross browser compatibility is difficult and often easier to achieve using javascript+css or jquery+css.

Comment: well how exactly would I do this using javascript + css?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, it's still a bug with Mozilla that messes up the styling, there is a workaround (kind of):

```
select {
overflow: hidden;
width: 125%;
}
```

Not sure about IE though

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work in mozilla either for me as it just pushed the arrow farther to the right

Comment: Hmm, it worked for me when I was messing around with CSS. I think it's because I had my own arrow, so I guess it shifted the default arrow behind my own arrow.

The bug is pretty old, and there seems no sign to it being fixed any time soon: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=649849.